# DataTables Warning, Invalid JSON response

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables-1.10

I am not able to produce any data from my datatable. it was working perfect on localhost but now the site is hosted on IIS I get an invalid JSON response.

I have fired up the dev tools and in the network tab and get the following

```
Request URL: http://odgh-webapp-uat/masks?_=1604435258024
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.146.16.194:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 20:27:36 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.6A-HjuGlSgs=CfDJ8FCglAuCLlJGqq2XVQMUUAUSieaecoWLJn7jobDBfMTOjwq6Zt8QUnrQJ7nS_GGmILzcdiyPJZG57YAQjb9R20dqsl9bbTc_mcmCwWDitum3mzfCW6Hz40GleUM8pqCY1ddr0isyCFOTohiI09hlJ4o
Host: odgh-webapp-uat
Referer: http://odgh-webapp-uat/masks/MaskList
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36 Edg/86.0.622.61
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

A look at my Jquery is below

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#DT-load').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/masks",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
           "dataSrc": "data",

        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "author", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "isbn", "width": "20%" },
            {

                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
                <a href="/MaskList/Edit?id=${data}" class='btn btn-success text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'>
                Edit
                </a>
            &nbsp;
            <a  class='btn btn-danger text-white mx-auto' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'
                    onclick=Delete('/masks?id='+${data})>
            Delete
                </a>
                </div>`;
                }, "width": "40"
            }

        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "No Data found"
        },
        "width": "100%"

    });

}


//Sweet Alert Function

function Delete(url) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once Delete you will not be able to recover",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true
    }).then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        toastr.success(data.message);
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(message);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    })

}
```

My controller looks correct and it worked fine during localhost

```
namespace MaskFit.Controllers
    {

    [Route("/mask")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MaskController : Controller
        {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public MaskController(ApplicationDbContext db)
            {

            _db = db;

            }

        [HttpGet]

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
            {
            return Json(new { data = await _db.Mask.ToListAsync() });
            }
```

Am I missing something obvious here? any help appreciated

Comment: Remove comma on `"dataSrc": "data",`. Also make sure the url is still ok.

Comment: Can attach the JSON returned from the server? I think there is a trick in the formatting like missing "data" in the returned data

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your data returned from server contains the attribute data like so:

```
{
  "data": [
            {...}
            {...}
          ]
}
```

Otherwise you should specify "dataSrc": ""